# Align vertical label of lightning:inputField in large screen

Tags: inputfield, label, lightning-recordeditform, component

I have a problem with lightning:inputField, in my page I have a mix of lighting:input and lightning:inputField.
When I dispaly inputField in large screen, the label is horizontally aligned with the input.

[image]

I would like to align it vertically.

There is my code

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="formAccount" 
                              objectApiName="Account">
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" />
                <lightning:input type="text"
                                 required="true"
                                 label="Account site"
                                 value="{!v.account.Site}" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
</aura:component>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your org moved to summer 19, please have look [new changes in summer 19](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm) , your use case you need to give density attribute for `lightning:recordeditform` please try below code

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name="account" type="Account" />
<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="formAccount" density="comfy" 
                          objectApiName="Account">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" value="{!v.account.Name}" />
            <lightning:input type="text"
                             required="true"
                             label="Account site"
                             value="{!v.account.Site}" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Comment: You're right, it works

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in my personal org and its working completely fine. When I dispalyed inputField in large screen, the label is aligned vertically with the label.

Try Element inspection by clicking F12, this would help you in finding what is going wrong.

Comment: When I use a large screen, this css class slds-form-element_stacked is replaced by slds-form-element_horizontal.
When I see the response of @sdandamud1 I think your org didn't moved to Summer'19